# Função virando objeto vazio quando enviada como props (React)

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

Estou com dificuldades na hora de enviar uma função de um componente para outro.

A função:

```
const plus = () => {
  setQuantity(quantity + 1);
}
```

Envio como uma prop no componente "Cart"

```
<Cart chosen={productDataObj} allchosen={chosenProducts} quantity={quantity} plus={plus}/>
```

Eu verifico qual tipo de variável "plus" está retornando dentro desse componente e ele retorna como objeto
[image: Output do console]

Trecho inicial de Cart.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

export default function Cart(chosen, plus){
 
const allChosen = chosen.allchosen;

 console.log(typeof(plus))
```

Em outro componente, no mesmo nível de Cart, onde eu passo outra função, ela chega corretamente.

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1):

ta faltando a desestruturação das props
assim como coloquei a baixo:

```
export default function Cart({chosen, plus}){

         seu componente ou console.log(typeof(plus))
   


}
```

Comment: Eu tentei assim mas o retorno é igual :(